# Next.js + react-gtm-module ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-gtm-module

I use this piece to initialize GTM in my Next.js app:

```
const tagManagerArgs = {
  gtmId: "GTM-XXXXXX"
};
TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs);
```

But when I am trying to start an app with it I am getting the error:

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.dataScript (/Users/username/work/projectname/node_modules/react-gtm-module/dist/TagManager.js:11:18)
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Hi there, not sure about your project struct but you must to put this inside your App.js, where are you exposing this code above?

Comment: I've already found the solution and put the answer, posted here just in case someone will face same issue.

Comment: Right, I'd suggestion to expose better why document was undefined and show a tiny nextjs structure, you refered it in labels but shown nothing related

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrapping the piece of TagManager initializer with a checker helped:

```
if (process.browser) {
  TagManager.initialize(tagManagerArgs);
}
```

Comment: talk about a specific answer. thank you! exact same question

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize TagManager right when the website has mounted to ensure that the DOM api is available

```
useEffect(()=>{
    TagManager.initialize({gtmId: 'GTM-XXXXXX'})
},[])
```